# ThinkPad L460 Wifi does not work

Tags: networking, wireless, drivers, thinkpad, iwlwifi

i want to apologize, but I have nerlay no knowledge of Linux/Ubuntu at all since this was my first try with it.

I was trying to set my Thinkpad L460 up with Ubuntu 14.04. After somehow i magicly got the touchpad to work, i had serious issues with my wifi.

Using lspci -nnk in terminal I found out, there is an Intel wifi card model 8260, but there was no cernel driver used.

So I tried lots of stuff I found on the internet, "emulating" my own driver,s updating kernel to 4.x doing a few ubuntu updates, installing the non-free-drivers for ubuntu, but nothing worked.

Does anyone know how to get the wifi running on this device and also can explain it very noob-friendly? :)

Comment: Ubuntu 14.10 is not supported for a long time.

Comment: I am sorry, 14.04 it is - i corrected.

Answer (score 0):

You need to upgrade the kernel. Run in terminal

```
sudo apt-get install linux-generic-lts-wily
sudo apt-get install linux-firmware
```

and reboot.

Comment: i did not get to try this, because i also tried lubuntu since i did read its more light weight and is recommended for laptops since it can save quite some energy. however after installing lubuntu without and upgrades, the wifi worked straight out of the box. I am not shure why however...
If i decide to go back to ubuntu i will definitely give your answer a try.

Comment: In lubuntu it works as well and it does not affect performance.

Comment: If I may ask - would you also recommend Ubuntu on a Laptop? It seemde more user friendly for People who are new to Linux than lubuntu, but lubuntu seemed more lightweight and faster and is also supposed to have lower power consumption.